# sublime - how to save file on close automatically

Tags: editor, text-editor, sublimetext2

How do I configure Sublime 2 to save files automatically that I close? It should behave like, User opens file, makes edits, closes file, and the edits are automatically saved even though the user did not manually save the edited file.

This is close, but I want it to save on file close rather than lose focus.

https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/settings.html
save_on_focus_lost

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that prompts thus doesn't save files automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want the file to be magically saved when just one is closed or when all your opened files (window) are closed? In the first case I suggest to open each file into a different window of SublimeText2.

In the second scenario you're looking for **hot_exit** : Preferences.sublime-settings

```
// Exiting the application with hot_exit enabled will cause it to close
// immediately without prompting. Unsaved modifications and open files will
// be preserved and restored when next starting.
//
// Closing a window with an associated project will also close the window
// without prompting, preserving unsaved changes in the workspace file
// alongside the project.
"hot_exit": true,
```

In addition to **remember_open_files** you can save automatically on exit and choose whether or not those files are opened next time.

Comment: but setting hot_exit to true is the DEFAULT and won't change anything. It.  Setting "hot_exit": false, doesn't save automatically, it prompts.  And setting remember_open_files to true or false makes no difference to the fact that it prompts. So, not automatic.